# Как использовать DataGridView для редактирования списка List<string>?

Tags: c#, winforms

Если просто привязать список строк через BindingSource,

```
var dgv = new DataGridView();
var list = new List<string> { "Petya", "Dima", "Masha" };
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = list;
dgv.DataSource = bs;
this.Controls.Add(dgv);
dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

[image: Скриншот формы]

, то получаем DataGridView с одним столбцом Length. А как добиться чтобы отображалось само значение элемента списка *"Petya", "Dima", "Masha"* ? Да так, чтобы изменения и добавляемые строки попадали обратно в `List<string>` ?

Comment: У `BindingSource` тоже есть события `AddingNew` и `ListChanged`. Поэтому можно обойтись без сторонней библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение с помощью [Equin.ApplicationFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView/) и мутабельной обёртки для string. Не очень нравится `.ToList()`, но для моей задачи не критично.

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "Petya", "Dima", "Masha" };

public class StringNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var dgv = new DataGridView();            
    var nodelist = list.Select(t => new StringNode { Value = t }).ToList();
    var bs = new Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView<StringNode>(nodelist);
    bs.AddingNew += (s,e) => e.NewObject = new StringNode();
    bs.ListChanged += (s,e) => 
    {
        list.Clear();
        foreach(var t in nodelist.Select(t=> t.Value))
        {
            list.Add(t); 
        }     
    };
    dgv.DataSource = bs;
    this.Controls.Add(dgv);
    dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    var btn = new Button { Text = "Display List" };
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    btn.Click += (s, e)
        => MessageBox.Show(string.Join("|", list));
}
```

[image: Скриншот формы]

Comment: `ToList` действительно нехорошо: мало того, что создаётся новый экземпляр списка при каждом редактировании (нагрузка на память и сборщик мусора), так ещё и в другом месте кода может остаться ссылка на _предыдущий_ список, то есть расхождение данных (и утечка памяти вероятна). Я бы изначально создал список не стрингов, а объектов нужного типа (вместо `StringNode` дал бы говорящее название типа `Person`) и далее везде работал с ними.